# Uneven CPU usage with NGINX

Tags: linux, nginx, central-processing-unit, cpu-usage, irq

On my CentOS 7 server, the load on each core is unequally distributed, as seen in the screenshot: some nginx worker seem to take way more load than other. `irqbalance`is enabled, hyperthreading disabled.

Any idea why ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

CPU 2 has at least a statsd task in addition to its nginx task. Migrating tasks to different CPUs is expensive, so not surprising that the scheduler stays like this for a while.

Load average of 7 to 8 on a 16 CPU system indicates that there are more CPUs than tasks ready to run. Remember that [CPU usage does not mean what you think it does](https://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-05-09/cpu-utilization-is-wrong.html), often CPU time is actually stalled waiting for memory or I/O.

Better, but more difficult to measure, performance metrics are focused on the user experience rather than host metrics. Perhaps request response time for nginx.